# Is InputStream.close() a blocking call in java?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I read from an input stream and in my finally block try to close it by calling in.close();
However the execution of main gets blocked . What is the way out ?

On suggestion , the code I used is ,

```
if (!processed) {
                System.out.println("in processed");
                byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
                Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
                FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
                FSDataInputStream in = null;
                try {
                    in = fs.open(file);
                    IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);

                    value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("before close stream");
                    IOUtils.closeStream(in);
                }
                processed = true;
                return true;
            }
            System.out.println("out of processed");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: without showing source code others cant easily.

Comment: @AdityaJain @ ILLA : Done :)

Comment: is "before close stream" printing on the console

Comment: similar post ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646940/why-does-javas-inputstream-close-block

Comment: @BhavikShah : yes .. I get that printed ..

Comment: You aren't even using `InputStream` here, and no, `InputStream.close()` does not block.

Comment: @BrianRoach : FSDataInputStream is a type of Input Stream fro Hadoop .

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say "You're not even using `InputStream.close()` here." You're using an apache library that hides exceptions from you to call it.

Comment: Sorry for the ridiculous question. I cannot find FileSystem.open() method in the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#getFileSystem(java.net.URI)

Comment: All operations on all Java streams are blocking, as it says in the Javadoc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

java.io.InputStream.close is not blocking, at least API never says that. Compare 
InputStream.read

```
 Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
 returned as an <code>int</code> in the range <code>0</code> to
 <code>255</code>. If no byte is available because the end of the stream
 has been reached, the value <code>-1</code> is returned. This method
 blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected,
 or an exception is thrown.
```

and  InputStream.close

```
  Closes this file input stream and releases any system resources
  associated with the stream.
```

As for solving your problem I would suggest to use Java 7 Files.readAllBytes and forget about your puzzle.

Comment: Cant use Files.readAllBytes because this is a part of an architecture that needs read to be done by defining start and end positions and into a buffer .

Comment: *All* I/O on streams is blocking.